# Excel - conditional formatting with 2 conditions

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

**hey ho! :-)**

I'm trying to get a rule in excel that combines two conditions:

- a specific cell has to be 0 [in this case: E9]
- the cell that should be formatted has the value "X" inside. [in this case: G9]

I tried these versions:

```
=AND(E9=0;EXACT(G9,"X")))

=AND(E9=0;IF(EXACT(G9,"X"),0,1)=0)
```

But excel doesn't accept this. There must be a mistake that I don't see.

Maybe you can help me?
Best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below should work :

=AND(E9=0,G9="X")

Comment: No, I'm sorry. It's not working. I just get an error from excel.

Answer (score -1):

=AND(E9=0;G9="X")

If I use a semicolon in the middle, it works! Thanks for helping! :)